# Nuget: Set one project in solution as unmanaged by Nuget?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

First off, let me start by saying that Nuget is awesome. I love it. That being said, there is one thing about it that I have just discovered which is really getting very annoying.

We have an in-house framework which we use for almost all of our projects. So, I recently created a Visual Studio project template for it, along with the VSIX.. had a few problems along the way due to Nuget.. it wouldn't create the new project from a template when the template was referencing the framework.. because the framework was using Nuget and it couldn't find the nuget folders in the new project created from the template. So, solution was to remove nuget from the framework project and only use Nuget for the other projects (anything but the framework). Okay, great.. that solves the problem!

However, now with every Nuget managed project that I open, it automatically adds these 2 lines back into the .csproj of the framework:

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

and

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

This is frustrating because we now need to either stop using Nuget altogether OR to keep removing these lines from our framework's .csproj file every time we want to rebuild the template.

Is there any way I can tell Nuget to ignore one project in the solution? In my case, to ignore the framework project...

Comment: I have really no experience with setting up Visual Studio templates, so I might be asking silly questions here: First of all, have you followed all the steps as described in the documentation (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates) for using NuGet packages in VS Templates? And also, this in-house framework of yours, how do you include that in all your other projects? Is this done as a NuGet package?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. First, I dont include nuget packages in my template. Although there is a packages.xml and so when we create the new project, we just set it to be managed by Nuget and then Nuget will auto detect those missing packages from the xml file and automatically download them...

Comment: ...The second thing is that we do not reference the framework (code library) by Nuget.. it is referenced as a project from the solution (Right click, Add existing project).. which of course we have to re-reference after the project is created. I need to look into multi-project templates later to solve that... anyway.. you may be thinking.. then just remove the reference from the project template. Well, if I do that, yes.. I suppose the project will be created.. but then the project template won't build (missing nuget folders problem, because the framework uses Nuget)...

Comment: ..and again.. if we remove Nuget from the framework (original plan), that's fine and it works, but then next time we open a different nuget-managed project which references the framework (same solution), then it automatically adds the framework to nuget management again... and we're back to the beginning again. Additionally, when we then open the solution for the framework, it complains of missing nuget folders also, because nuget was enabled from an external solution and not the main framework's solution.

Comment: And in case anyone is wondering why we add the code library to the solution instead of referencing a versioned DLL... it is because the library is constantly changing and being updated with every new project.. it is modified on a daily basis.. so using DLLs is not really an option for us

Comment: @Nailuj, I just took a look at your link and also I found this: http://samritchie.net/2012/09/17/nuget-packages-in-vs2012-templates/.. it might actually do the trick. I will give it a go later and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a suggestion from Nailuj and also from what I found here: http://samritchie.net/2012/09/17/nuget-packages-in-vs2012-templates/, I tried something that I thought would work, but it didn't serve my needs; that method is just for including the packages in with the new project, which for me is not helpful and doesn't solve the problem (error about missing .nuget targets folders). So, I played with it a bit and came up with something that is not ideal, but is acceptable:

1. Remove anything and everything to do with Nuget from the project which is to serve as a template. This then causes a problem with the referenced framework, because the framework project is expecting to be managed by Nuget and from this solution it's not, so error occurs... so:
2. Remove the framework project from the solution and only reference the DLL so it will build, but not complain about missing nuget folders
3. Rebuild
4. Export to template
5. Build VSIX using exported template
6. Install template
7. Create a new project from the newly installed template
8. Enable Nuget package restore on solution of new project
9. Open Package Manager Console
10. Notice message about missing packages and agree to download and install them (about 1 minute)
11. Remove framework DLL reference and replace with actual project (Right-click, Add Existing Project)
12. Rebuild and run
13. Celebrate!

I hope this helps anyone else who may find themselves in this predicament. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know. The bounty is still open for another 6 days, so I won't mark this as answer yet.